# How do I redisplay an array after a mergesort algorithm so that each step is shown?

Tags: c#, sorting, format

This is my mergesort method for sorting an array, it displays the sorted array fine, but how would I show each partially solved step?

```js
 public void mergeSort(string[] sortArray, int lower, int upper)
        {
            int middle;
            if (upper == lower)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                middle = (lower + upper) / 2;
                mergeSort(sortArray, lower, middle);
                mergeSort(sortArray, middle + 1, upper);
                Merge(sortArray, lower, middle + 1, upper);
            }
            
        }
```

I was thinking of adding

foreach (string a in sortArray)
            {
                txtOutput.Text += a + "\t";
            }

To the end of the array, but then when I display the sorted method, all the partial solutions display together. Into something like

Sorted array:
1 8 7 3 1 7 3 8 1 3 7 8 1 3 7 8

I want to display it as

Partially sorted array:

1 8 7 3

1 7 3 8

1 3 7 8

Sorted array:

1 3 7 8

Comment: Just for fun: http://visualgo.net/sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the foreach loop append a newline('\n') to your output string.

```
if(lower == 0 && upper == sortArray.Length-1)
   output +="Sorted Array:\n"

foreach(var a in sortedArray)
{
//Display Logic
}
```

Comment: that helped, but how would I separately display the partially solved solution and the solved one? right now they just display in one string

Comment: an if condition would work. lower==0 && upper==sortArray.Length-1 then it would mean we have a fully sorted array.

Comment: Don't worry. I got it haha. WOOT. thanks for the tip about the \n though :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix - just change "\t" to "\t\n" and you're good to go.
Hope this helps.

Comment: that didn't do anything haha

Answer (score 0):

For a "prettier" display, this is an example of the order of operations for a top down merge sort, which is depth first, left first. The vertical bars represent the split between left and right halves of the current array. The display shows the initial state, then the state after a split and after a merge.

```
|4 2 8 6 0 5 1 7 3 9|
|4 2 8 6 0|5 1 7 3 9|
|4 2|8 6 0|
|4|2|
|2 4|
    |8|6 0|
      |6|0|
      |0 6|
    |0 6 8|
|0 2 4 6 8|
          |5 1|7 3 9|
          |5|1|
          |1 5|
              |7|3 9|
                |3|9|
                |3 9|
              |3 7 9|
          |1 3 5 7 9|
|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9|
```

This is an example of the order of operations for a bottom up merge sort after each merge pass. The vertical bars represent sorted run boundaries.

```
|4 2 8 6 0 5 1 7 3 9|
|4|2|8|6|0|5|1|7|3|9|
|2 4|6 8|0 5|1 7|3 9|
|2 4 6 8|0 1 5 7|3 9|
|0 1 2 4 5 6 7 8|3 9|
|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9|
```